# Primefaces Panels don't update collapsed status after a dialog was dismissed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm seeing a strange behaviour with Primefaces (4.0) related to Panels whose collapsed-attributes are bound to a property in a backing bean. Updating the state works fine so the panel collapses/expands correctly when the value of the backing bean changes. 
The problem is: I have some p:Dialogs that can be opened to enter some additional/optional information. After closing the dialog, the panel fails to expand/collapse when changing the value. Strangely, other attributes bound to the same property get updated like before.

**Example**:
XHTML of two panels whose collapsed Attribute is bound to a property. Note that the disabled-attribute of the checkboxes are bound to the same property and still get updated after the dialog is closed.

```
<p:panel id="panel1" style="width:80%;" toggleable="true" collapsed="#{!bean.panel1.enabled}" widgetVar="panel1Var">
        <f:facet name="header">
        <p:outputLabel value="Panel1"/>
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="p1_enabled" style="margin-left:20px;" disabled="#{bean.panel2.enabled}" value="#{bean.panel1.enabled}">
        <f:ajax  render="panel1 panel2" />
        </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</f:facet>  
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%;" columnClasses="input-col1,input-col2">
    <!-- omitted -->
    </p:panelGrid>
</p:panel>

<p:panel id="panel2" style="width:80%;" toggleable="true" collapsed="#{!bean.panel2.enabled}" widgetVar="panel2Var">
        <f:facet name="header">
        <p:outputLabel value="Panel2"/>
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="p2_enabled" style="margin-left:20px;" disabled="#{bean.panel1.enabled}" value="#{bean.panel2.enabled}">
        <f:ajax  render="panel1 panel2" />

        </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</f:facet>  
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%;" columnClasses="input-col1,input-col2">
    <!-- omitted -->
    </p:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
```

XHTML somewhere else on the same page which opens a dialog:

```
<p:commandLink id="contactbutton" onclick="PF('contactextended').show();">
        <h:outputText value="Extended" />
    </p:commandLink>
```

The dialog is configured like this:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="contactextended" modal="true" width="600px" height="500px" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false" draggable="false">
```

The backing bean is a straightforward bean with properties and getters/setter which obviously work. Is there a problem in my implementation? Any ideas how to work around this issue? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by myself. The solution seems to be to add `process="@this"`to the commandLink. I am still not sure what the underlying problem is/was, but at least it doesn't get triggered anymore.